# On login screen layout keeps showing - React & React router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

As I mentioned I have MUI Theme Provider with Layout which includes Dashboard, Order screens ...

When user hits '/' endpoint it should return Login Screen but Layout keeps showing itself.

-App.js

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
<Router>
  <Layout>
  <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <Route  path="/dashboard">
        <Dashboard />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/orders">
        <Orders />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/users">
        <Users />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/employees">
        <Employee />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Layout>
</Router>
</ThemeProvider>
```

);

-Layout.js

...AppBar,Sidebar etc

```
<div style={{width:'100%'}}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar}></div>
       {children}
</div>
```

Comment: Can't understand the question ... Layout component is outside the switch statement so it's normal behaviour is to keep showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As-is, the code is unconditionally rendering a `Layout` component outside the `Switch`, so it's rendered regardless of the currently matched route.

If you want the `Layout` component to only render on certain routes, conditionally render it with those routes.

Example, render the `Login` component on exactly the `"/"` path, everything else into a route rendering the `Layout` and another `Switch`.

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <Route  path="/dashboard">
              <Dashboard />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/orders">
              <Orders />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/users">
              <Users />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/employees">
              <Employee />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</ThemeProvider>
```